# Sitecore cacheable & Cassette

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Inside of my rendering's markup, I'm adding a reference to a series of .less files using the `Bundles.Reference`. When I enable caching on this component, the less files won't get added to the `<head>`.

```
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{
    Bundles.Reference("~/resources/less/interior", "header");
}
```

Comment: If you enable caching, the code is not executed anymore (after the first time) so it's normal that your references are not added anymore, no?

Comment: you're right. I'm trying to figure out how I can cache the result & keep the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Move your Cassette's `Renderings` into a viewer rendering.

```
@Bundles.RenderStylesheets("global")
@Bundles.RenderStylesheets("header")
@Bundles.RenderScripts("global")
@Bundles.RenderScripts("header")
```

Add this rendering to sitecore. As seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV4Qj.png).

Add your rendering to your layout. This will cache it by the page hits.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<your rendering definition item id>", new { Cacheable = true, CacheKey = "my_rendering", Cache_VaryByData = true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both cache (output cache) and expect your code to be executed. So either you cache, but then you need to put that code somewhere else. Or you don't (output) cache. But (output) cache and executing the code are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Of course, you can. I'm working on a solution right now.

Comment: You added another rendering, so you actually moved the code "somewhere else" like I said.. ;)

Comment: you ended up being right. I realized that half way into it ;-). Either way, that worked, and we didn't have to change the .less implementations across the site.